# How to access request object of django in react?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, babeljs

I have multiple apps in my Django project but for One app I would like to use react, so I have create two apps one for apis and other for frontend.
I used webpack to merge django and react.
Now I want to access `request.user` and `user.is_authenticated` in my components.
How can I access those without calling apis as I am not using token-based authentication so I can not call APIs.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$',index),
]
```

I would like to use is_authenticated in my sidebar everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the request user and is_authenticated to the context of the index view and access it in your React components via the window object.

In your views.py:

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'is_authenticated': request.user.is_authenticated,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

In your index.html:

```
<script>
  window.user = {{ user|safe }}
  window.is_authenticated = {{ is_authenticated|safe }}
</script>
```

Comment: without "", it says `True` is not defined and with, i am getting True as string but I want bool.

Comment: Solved it by using {{ request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true,false" }}; Thank you.